# delegate method never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

first of all here is my code:

```
@protocol SearchTableViewControllerDelegate

@required
- (void)didSelectFileCardsContent:(FileCardsContent*)content;

@end


@interface SearchTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>{

    id <SearchTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
...
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SearchTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
...
@end
---------------------------------------------------

@implementation SearchTableViewController

@synthesize ... delegate;
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FileCardsContent *fileCardToShow = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.delegate didSelectFileCardsContent:fileCardToShow];

}
...
@end
---------------------------------------------------

@interface FileCardsViewCotroller : UIViewController <SearchTableViewControllerDelegate>{
...
@end
---------------------------------------------------

@implementation FileCardsViewCotroller
...
- (void)didSelectFileCardsContent:(FileCardsContent*)content{
    [managedFileCards insertSingleContent:content];
    self.currentFileCardsContent = content;
    questionView1.text = currentFileCardsContent.question;

}
@end
```

My problem is  - (void)didSelectFileCardsContent:(FileCardsContent*)content in FileCardsViewCotroller is never called.
There are no compiler warnings or errors. I`m not familiar with protocols and delegates so is suggest there is a conceptually problem.
Anny ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just aren't assigning your delegate to anything so the message is sent to nil.

Comment: sound reasonable, but how do I assign my delegate?

Comment: @Jonas Set your delegate in FileCardsViewCotroller with [mySearchController setDelegate:self]

Answer (score 1):

first it's good practice to check whether the method exists/is implemented by the delegate

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectFileCardsContent:)])
    [delegate didSelectFileCardsContent:fileCardToShow];
```

don't use self.property when you're calling it in its own class. it executes unnecessary commands when you can just call it directly.

make sure you implemented the protocol in the delegate and implemented the method.
make sure you set the delegate to self.

Comment: the if statement is FALSE I think the reason therefore is the answer of Oscar Gomez

Comment: if you care to read my whole answer. i believe i explicitly told you what oscar's answer meant.

Comment: Now that I understand delegates a little bit better your right. Before I did not knew what you mean with "set the delegate to self."